# Drupal 8 Custom Composite Entity Select Field

Tags: webforms

Does anyone have an example of how I add an Entity Select (Specifically a term reference) to a custom composite?

Here's the code I've tired. The field with the title shows up but no select.

```
$elements['test_tax'] = [
  '#type' => 'entity_select',
  '#title' => t('Test Taxonomy'),
  '#target_type' => 'taxonomy_term',
  '#selection_handler' => 'default:taxonomy_term',
  '#selection_settings' => [
    'target_bundles' => [
      'my_terms' => 'my_terms'
    ],
    'sort' => [
      'field' => 'name',
      'direction' => 'ASC'
    ]
  ] 
];
```

I'm a front-end guy so I'm a bit out of my element in php...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just need to change...

```
'#type' => 'entity_select',
```

...to...

```
'#type' => 'webform_entity_select',
```

In the Webform YAML source editor we are hiding the 'webform_*' prefixes, within custom code they have to included.

@see https://cgit.drupalcode.org/webform/tree/src/Element/WebformEntitySelect.php

Comment: That was it!

Thanks for making the example module for composites as well. Even a as a non-php dev I was able to get it pretty close. Major kudo's to you guys.